# How to differentiate dimens for two different DPI

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using Pixel which has 420dpi density and Moto x4 which has a density of 480dpi density. Both use same value folder i.e. **values-xxhdpi.**

But, the layout gets large on Moto x4. Is there any way to differentiate different dimens folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly you can use

**smallest width dp**: the smallest width available for application layout in “dp” units; this is the smallest width dp that you will ever encounter in any rotation of the display.

To create one right click on **res** >>> **new** >>> **Android resource directory**

From **Available qualifiers** window move **Smallest Screen Width** to **Chosen qualifiers**

In **Screen width** window just write the "dp" value starting from you would like Android Studio to use that dimens.

Than change to **Project** view,right click on your new created resource directory

**new** >>> **Values resource file** enter a new file name **dimens.xml** and you are done.